# How to autowire SecurityContextRepository by class implementation

Tags: java, ajax, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to do an Ajax login with a code i taked overthere, this is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")

public class AjaxLoginController {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("AuthenticationManager")
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
SecurityContextRepository repository;

@Autowired
RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void login() {}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String performLogin(
    @RequestParam("j_username") String username, 
    @RequestParam("j_password") String password,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    try {
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            repository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);
            rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
            return "{\"status\": true}";
    } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return "{\"status\": false, \"error\": \"Bad Credentials\"}";
    }
}
}
```

This example have an xml configuration of beans for the autowire, but my project requires to do it by class configuration. I solved the first autowire issue adding this to my security class configuration:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationManager();
}
```

Now i'm trying to do the something with the securityContextRepository but all that i find on forums are xml configurations solutions. 
Anyone knows how configure this class as Bean to solve this? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` is the default implementation for `SecurityContextRepository`. Add this to the configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
}
```

Note that the name of the bean is `securityContextRepository` and not `repository` which, I think, reduces any possible ambiguity.